# How to upgrade lighttpd 1.4.33 to 1.4.47 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I have installed lighttpd using:

sudo apt-get install lighttpd

However, the version installed is 1.4.33.

How can i upgrade to the latest stable release which is 1.4.47?

Edit: Looks like i can only upgrade to 1.4.45. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. [It's the latest](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lighttpd) available. It takes some time to prepare a package from upstream, and sometimes fixes gets backported from upstream as well.

[Here is the overview for the package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lighttpd), and the newest in any Ubuntu appears to be 1.4.45. If you **need** features in the latest, you're basically left with either compiling lighttpd yourself, or upgrading to a newer Ubuntu relase. 1.4.45 is also what's provided by [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/lighttpd) in sid.

If you worry about security issues, check if these are backported.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i upgrade to 1.4.45?

Comment: You probably can't. Not without upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release. But you *can* compile the newest 1.4.47 by hand for 14.04.